# Conjugacy classes of Weyl group of type B

Tags: representation-theory, coxeter-groups, weyl-group

I'm really stuck in proving the fact that the conjugacy classes of B_n are deterimined by a positive and negative cycle stractures. Can you give me any hint. 
I think if I can use the fact that $g(i_1,i_2,\cdot,i_k)g^{-1}= (gi_1,gi_2,\cdot,gi_k)$ but I'm not sure if this would work. Also how this gives a bijection with the complementary partitions of $n.$